# How can I bind two sockets to the same port on two separate programs?

Tags: java, python, sockets, server, client

I have a server.java and a client.python file. When I try the following, however, I get a "[Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error. Is there a way around this? Why is this happening?
client.py

```
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 sockRecv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 sock.bind((socket.gethostname(),4000))
 sockRecv.bind((socket.gethostname(),4000 + 1))
```

server.java

```
recvSocket = new DatagramSocket(4000);
sendSocket = new DatagramSocket(4000 + 1);
```

Comment: They both don't bind to the same port. Rethink it so that one is the server and the other is the client. The server binds to the port, the other connects to the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code is doing doesn't make sense, to me.

The IP address + port represents an end-point for datagram communication.  If two applications were able to bind to the same end-point, which of them would receive the packets sent to the end-point?  One of them?  Both of them?

UDP is not a multi-cast protocol .... unless you bind to a multicast IP address.

---

Based on hints in your code (names of variables) I think you are trying to set up message passing between two applications on the same host.  If so you should do this:

- Application A binds to port P1 and sends messages to port P2
- Application B binds to port P2 and sends messages to port P1.

There is no need for applications A and B bind to the same end-point; i.e. the same port ... to do what I think you are trying to do.